# Google Chrome can't show fav icon

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser, favicon

Google Chrome can't show the fav icon of the website http://www.hausnaturpur.de/

Whereas Firefox and other browsers support the fav icon. 
This is the code used:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/newfavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" 
      href="http://www.hausnaturpur.de/images/newfavicon.ico">
```

If it works, than you should try this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/newfavicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try moving the image to root folder such that the new path for image would be `http://www.hausnaturpur.de/newfavicon.ico`

Answer (score 0):

from looking at the source of SO

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
```

also an article from wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

I would suggest checking that the image is being sent through by pressing f12 on your keyboard inside of Chrome and checking the network tab (you will have to do a refresh for it to work). The only other thing i can suggest is renaming your icon file to favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the same row with only "icon" in the rel attribute.